# Line spacing issue in tables

Tags: tables, line-spacing

In the following code , describing a table. The second horizintal line, appears to smudge with line of text.

How can I correct that?

[image: The yellow highlited]

The question is, then: how do i increase the line spacing between the line and the text?

```
 \resheading{\textbf{ACADEMIC DETAILS} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{5mm} \vfill
%\begin{table}[ht!]
%\begin{center}
\indent \begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l }
\hline
\vspace{0.1mm}
\textbf{Year} &\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institute}   & \textbf{CGPA/\%} \\
\hline
2015- Present&B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering & VIT Vellore  & 9.69 CGPA \\

2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 94.8\%\\

2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 10 CGPA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
%\end{table}
\vspace{2mm}

%\resheading{\textbf
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: And rework your table using `booktabs`. It provides nicer rules for exactly this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution consists in defining a *minimal* vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells with the `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{Sl}@{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Year} &\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institute} & \textbf{CGPA/\%}\\
        \midrule
        2015 -- present & B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering & VIT Vellore & 9.69 CGPA\\
        2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 94.8\%\\
        2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 10 CGPA\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As [Alan Munn also suggested in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364859/line-spacing-issue-in-tables#comment898859_364859): Don't worry and let `booktabs` take care of your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-15pt}{@{}lXll@{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Year} &\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institute} & \textbf{CGPA/\%}\\
        \midrule
        2015 -- present & B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering & VIT Vellore & 9.69 CGPA\\
        2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 94.8\%\\
        2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 10 CGPA\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem  of  row spacing when there's no rule.

Comment: @Bernard No it does not -- but I saw no hints in the question, that the spacing between the rows should be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

As suggested in *Alan Munn* in his comment, rules from `booktabs` package gives more vertical space around cells contents. Beside this the `\arraystretch` is increase and removed surplus manual spacing between columns.

```
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l l }
\midrule
\textbf{Year} 
     & \textbf{Degree}  & \textbf{Institute}   & \textbf{CGPA/\%}   \\
\midrule
2015- Present
     & B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering  
                        & VIT Vellore           & 9.69 CGPA         \\

2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination 
                        & Kendriya Vidyalaya    & 94.8\%            \\

2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination 
                        & Kendriya Vidyalaya    & 10 CGPA           \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
}
```