# Options for line spacing, other than vspace and vfill

Tags: line-spacing

I have a document where there is problem is line spacing.

What are the other options for line spacing other than `\vfill` and `\vspace`?

Here is the code which shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\star$}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}
\selectfont
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
%[ansinew]
[utf8]
{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\textheight=9.75in
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-2 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.5cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{-0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.62in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}
\hspace{0.5cm}\\[-0.2cm]

\textbf{Anupam Bisht} \\
\indent $2^{nd}$ Year, B.Tech Student\\
\indent Electrical and Electronics Engineering
\hfill Ph: +91 7200660151\\
\indent VIT University, Vellore, TN -632014
\hfill Email: anupam.bisht2015@vit.ac.in \\

\resheading{\textbf{OBJECTIVE} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{4mm} \vfill
\indent To obtain a job in a core-company so that the technical skills and the knowledge acquired during the past \indent can  be used to develop a new solution or optimize existing solutions for the profit of company as well as \indent betterment of the society.

\vspace{2mm}
\resheading{\textbf{ACADEMIC DETAILS} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{5mm} \vfill
%\begin{table}[ht!]
%\begin{center}
\indent \begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l }
\hline
\vspace{0.1mm}
\textbf{Year} &\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institute}   & \textbf{CGPA/\%} \\
\hline
2015- Present&B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering & VIT Vellore  & 9.69 CGPA \\

2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 94.8\%\\

2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 10 CGPA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
%\end{table}
\vspace{2mm}

%\resheading{\textbf{FIELDS OF INTEREST} }\\[\lsep]
%\begin{itemize}
%\item \noindent Wireless Network and Network Security, %Another one, a third one
%\end{itemize}
\resheading{\textbf{AREA OF INTEREST} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{1.0mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Medical Sensors, circuit design, computer interfacing of hardware, control systems.
\end{itemize}
\vfill

\resheading{\textbf{TECHNICAL SKILLS} }\\[\lsep]
\vfill \vspace{1.0mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent \textbf{Languages:\space} C ,\space C++,\space Python, \space R
\item \noindent \textbf{Tools:\space}MATLAB,\space Orcad Pspice,\space Arduino\space, LabView ,\space\LaTeX
\item \noindent \textbf{Platforms:\space} Linux and Windows
\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{PROJECTS} }\\[\lsep]
\vfill \vspace{0.5mm}
\begin{itemize}\itemsep2pt
\item \textbf{Calculation of HeartBeat using Photoplethysmogram in LabVIEW.} \textit{(Feburary 2017 - Currently Working)}
\end{itemize}
\indent We have designed to algorithms, which are inspired from the Pan-Tompkins Algorithm for QRS waveform detection for calculation of heartbeat. We also trying to do statistical analysis of the data using the R software


\resheading{\textbf{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent  A volunteer at Kulethi primary school Champawat,Uttarakhand. I helped to promote tablet assisted teaching in the primary school.Also helped in video making of basic science experiments in Hindi, which are uploaded in YouTube.(June 2016)

\item \noindent  Core Committee member at IEEE student chapter of VIT University.
(October 2015 - March 2016)

\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{ACHIEVEMENTS} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for ranking 3rd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2016-17.

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for ranking 2nd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2015-16.

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for scoring 10 CGPA in class 10th Board Examination.

\item \noindent  Selected to represent KVS for Jawaharlal Nehru National Science, Mathematics and Environment Exhibition for children(JNNSMEE) held at Gangtok, Sikkim during November 2013.

\item \noindent  Awarded 3rd Prize at KVS National Level Science Exhibition held at Kendriya Vidiyalaya Ballygunge, Kolkata for the project titled "Principle of Fiber Optic Communication and Related  Applications" in the year 2012.

\end{itemize}


%\resheading{\textbf{MAJOR PROJECTS AND SEMINAR} }\\[\lsep]
%\begin{itemize}
%\item \textbf{Media Access Control Controling
%} (Research Project) \\
% \emph{(Guide:Prof. Hubert F.
%, May'13 - till date)} \\[-0.6cm]
%   \begin{itemize}\itemsep \isep
%   \item Objective :Performance analysis of HTTP web browsing traffic.
%.
%   \item Performance analysis will help in comparing different MAC protocols based on different network sce-
%narios.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: There is manual spacing littered all over the place. `\\[\lsep]\vfill \vspace{1.0mm}`  Know hat this is doing? Gets into a new line, removes half a centimeter vertical space, pushing everything down and saving a centimeter of space. And this is going on multiple times. Your document is a mess.

Comment: In my opinion, you should remove the word LaTeX from your resume.  Your way is not the way to use it. You would be better of using plainTeX.

Comment: Related: [Line spacing issue in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364859/line-spacing-issue-in-tables) and [Line spacing issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364852/line-spacing-issues)

Comment: I vote to close as duplicate of the question posted a few hours ago. This question was answered by David Carlisle. This question asks for alternatives to `vfill` and `vspace`, commands that shouldn't even be used (also explained by DPC). Obvious errors that wer mentioned haven't been fixed but dragged around further. If it isn't enough that LaTeX *and* DPC tell you that `Font shape \`T1/SansSerif/m/n' undefined` is to be taken seriously, i wil do as well: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX is designed so, that vertical spaces (in normal circumstances) are defined global. Consequently manual tweaking of distance between items, paragraphs etc is surplus. Even more, it destroy document consistency and make it ugly.

I try to cleanup all surplus stuff in your code as `\indent after`\item`, manual correction of vertical space, use of`\textbf{...}`in`\resheading` (it is already in its definition), etc.

Also I redesign `\resheading` where I add vertical space before and after it and correct its width. For table I use answers from your previous questions, for `itemize` I use `enumitem` package.

Since you use `a4paper` I also change all imperial units to SI units (mm). On the end I obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{palatino}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}\selectfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{url}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\medskip
    \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}\small 
                        \textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}
                      \end{minipage}}
                            \par\medskip}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{\textbf{#1}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}

\textbf{Anupam Bisht} \\
$2^{nd}$ Year, B.Tech Student\\
Electrical and Electronics Engineering
\hfill Ph: +91 7200660151\\
VIT University, Vellore, TN -632014
\hfill Email: anupam.bisht2015@vit.ac.in \\

\resheading{OBJECTIVE}
To obtain a job in a core-company so that the technical skills and the knowledge acquired during the past \indent can  be used to develop a new solution or optimize existing solutions for the profit of company as well as \indent betterment of the society.

\resheading{\textbf{ACADEMIC DETAILS} }
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X l l}
    \midrule
\textbf{Year}
     & \textbf{Degree}  & \textbf{Institute}   & \textbf{CGPA/\%}   \\
    \midrule
2015- Present
     & B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering
                        & VIT Vellore           & 9.69 CGPA         \\

2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination
                        & Kendriya Vidyalaya    & 94.8\%            \\

2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination
                        & Kendriya Vidyalaya    & 10 CGPA           \\
    \midrule
\end{tabularx}

\resheading{\textbf{AREA OF INTEREST} }
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Medical Sensors, circuit design, computer interfacing of hardware, control systems.
    \end{itemize}

\resheading{TECHNICAL SKILLS} 
    \begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Languages:\space} C ,\space C++,\space Python, \space R
\item \textbf{Tools:} MATLAB,\space Orcad Pspice,\space Arduino\space, LabView ,\space\LaTeX
\item \textbf{Platforms:} Linux and Windows
    \end{itemize}

\resheading{PROJECTS}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   \textbf{Calculation of HeartBeat using Photoplethysmogram in LabVIEW.} \textit{(Feburary 2017 - Currently Working)}
    \end{itemize}
We have designed to algorithms, which are inspired from the Pan-Tompkins Algorithm for QRS waveform detection for calculation of heartbeat. We also trying to do statistical analysis of the data using the R software

\resheading{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   A volunteer at Kulethi primary school Champawat,Uttarakhand. I helped to promote tablet assisted teaching in the primary school.Also helped in video making of basic science experiments in Hindi, which are uploaded in YouTube.(June 2016)
\item   Core Committee member at IEEE student chapter of VIT University.
(October 2015 - March 2016)
    \end{itemize}

\resheading{ACHIEVEMENTS}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Awarded with cash prize for ranking 3rd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2016-17.
\item   Awarded with cash prize for ranking 2nd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2015-16.
\item   Awarded with cash prize for scoring 10 CGPA in class 10th Board Examination.
\item   Selected to represent KVS for Jawaharlal Nehru National Science, Mathematics and Environment Exhibition for children(JNNSMEE) held at Gangtok, Sikkim during November 2013.
\item   Awarded 3rd Prize at KVS National Level Science Exhibition held at Kendriya Vidiyalaya Ballygunge, Kolkata for the project titled "Principle of Fiber Optic Communication and Related  Applications" in the year 2012.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you like to have different spacing in list, you can change this with option `\itemsep` in `\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}`. For details, see package documentation. To my opinion default settigns are well selected.